# How to use a custom induction principle in Coq?

Tags: coq, induction, coq-tactic

I read that the induction principle for a type is just a theorem about a proposition `P`. So I constructed an induction principle for `List` based on the right (or reverse) list constructor .

```
Definition rcons {X:Type} (l:list X) (x:X) : list X := 
  l ++ x::nil.
```

The induction principle itself is:

```
Definition true_for_nil {X:Type}(P:list X -> Prop) : Prop :=
  P nil.

Definition true_for_list {X:Type} (P:list X -> Prop) : Prop :=
  forall xs, P xs.

Definition preserved_by_rcons {X:Type} (P: list X -> Prop): Prop :=
  forall xs' x, P xs' -> P (rcons xs' x).

Theorem list_ind_rcons: 
  forall {X:Type} (P:list X -> Prop),
    true_for_nil P ->
    preserved_by_rcons P ->
    true_for_list P.
Proof. Admitted.
```

But now, I am having trouble using the theorem. I don't how to invoke it to achieve the same as the `induction` tactic.

For example, I tried:

```
Theorem rev_app_dist: forall {X} (l1 l2:list X), rev (l1 ++ l2) = rev l2 ++ rev l1.
Proof. intros X l1 l2. 
  induction l2 using list_ind_rcons.
```

But in the last line, I got:

```
Error: Cannot recognize an induction scheme.
```

What are the correct steps to define and apply a custom induction principle like `list_ind_rcons`?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you did was mostly correct. The problem is that Coq has some trouble recognizing that what you wrote is an induction principle, because of the intermediate definitions. This, for instance, works just fine:

```
Theorem list_ind_rcons:
  forall {X:Type} (P:list X -> Prop),
    P nil ->
    (forall x l, P l -> P (rcons l x)) ->
    forall l, P l.
Proof. Admitted.

Theorem rev_app_dist: forall {X} (l1 l2:list X), rev (l1 ++ l2) = rev l2 ++ rev l1.
Proof. intros X l1 l2.
  induction l2 using @list_ind_rcons.
```

I don't know if Coq not being able to automatically unfold the intermediate definitions should be considered a bug or not, but at least there is a workaround.

Comment: I think you meant `(forall x l, P l -> P (l ++ (x :: nil))) ->`

Comment: @gallais indeed, thanks for spotting it. Just fixed it.

Comment: In Coq, there is long standing disrespect for definitional equality in the implementation of tactics. Whilst this is questionable, ideologically, it is far too late to do anything about it in practice.

Answer (score 7):

If one would like to preserve the intermediate definitions, then one could use the `Section` mechanism, like so:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List. Import ListNotations.

Definition rcons {X:Type} (l:list X) (x:X) : list X := 
  l ++ [x].

Section custom_induction_principle.    
  Variable X : Type.
  Variable P : list X -> Prop.

  Hypothesis true_for_nil : P nil.
  Hypothesis true_for_list : forall xs, P xs.
  Hypothesis preserved_by_rcons : forall xs' x, P xs' -> P (rcons xs' x).

  Fixpoint list_ind_rcons (xs : list X) : P xs. Admitted.
End custom_induction_principle.
```

Coq substitutes the definitions and `list_ind_rcons` has the needed type and `induction ... using ...` works:

```
Theorem rev_app_dist: forall {X} (l1 l2:list X),
  rev (l1 ++ l2) = rev l2 ++ rev l1.
Proof. intros X l1 l2. 
  induction l2 using list_ind_rcons.
Abort.
```

By the way, this induction principle is present in the standard library ([`List`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Lists.List.html) module):

```
Coq < Check rev_ind.
rev_ind
     : forall (A : Type) (P : list A -> Prop),
       P [] ->
       (forall (x : A) (l : list A), P l -> P (l ++ [x])) ->
       forall l : list A, P l
```